# Creating a setup for a project in visual studio with a sql database on localhost

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, mysql-workbench

Im creating a project on visual studio using .net and im going to need to create a setup to install the project on another computer but i have no ideia how to include the database that is on my localhost

I created the database with MySQL workbench.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should provide your question and works briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Install Shield** to create exe/setup file.
here you can download
https://info.flexerasoftware.com/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio

If you want to more customization use **Advance Installer**
here you can download Advance Installer
https://www.advancedinstaller.com/

For Database you need install SQL Server or MYSQL workbench. Just make sure correct server name.